# "window is not defined" nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js

в данном фрагменте кода использую слушатели события. при сборке выдается ошибка "window is not defined". 
подскажите, как это можно обойти? NUXT JS!

```js
methods: {
    onResize() {
      this.onMobileCondition = window.innerWidth <= 600;
    }
  },
  
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
    this.onResize();
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  }
```

**update:** ошибка аналогичная со слайдером. как обойти?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте обернуть все, что написано внутри `created()` и `destroyed()` в `if (process.browser) { }`.
документация накст: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/